# create templated button in wpf with different properties

Tags: wpf

I created a custom button. I need more buttons of same style with different backgrounds. It is possible to do this with creating templates for each button. But that eliminates code reusabilty. Is it possible to apply the same template for all buttons but with some change in properties like the background.
Here is my code.

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="custom-button" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="btn_image">
                <Image Name="btnBackground" Source="Media/Knob Red.png"></Image>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRunning}" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="btnBackground" Property="Source" Value="Media/Knob Play.png"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

This is my button for which i applied the template.

```
<Button Name="start" Template="{StaticResource  custom-button}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" Height="30" Click="Start_Click">
</Button>
```

Now i need to use the template for a few more buttons but they should have different backgrounds. What to change. tried many methods but no single luck.

These are my other buttons.

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource  custom-button}" Name="reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" Height="30" Click="Reset_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Media/Knob Refresh.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
</Button>
 <Button Template="{StaticResource  custom-button}" x:Name="close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Height="18" RenderTransformOrigin="1.771,-1.3" Click="Close">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Media/Knob Purple.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following inside your custom control:

```
 <Image Name="btnBackground" Source="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Image>
```

And in your button declaration you can pass the image as background property.

Comment: Well you can do Like background={staticResource ResourceKey=key}.

And the key is the key of ImageBrush declared as a static resource. in your control